# Variations of earth's magnetic field strength among different geographical locations

Tags: geophysics, geomagnetism

Is it true that on average, people who grow up in a geographical location of the earth where the magnetic field strength is stronger than other geographical locations, develop more to their genetic potential and experience less degenerative medical problems and less cases of cancer compared to people who grow up in geographical locations where the earth's magnetic field is weaker (less)?  Is it true that during ancient times, intelligent beings used the placing of stones in various locations of some countries such as Scotland, England, Ireland, Egypt, America, or South America, to mark various locations where the Earth's magnetic field lines were the strongest in their particular location and / or, in different locations? This is a question pertaining to the physics of molecular biology and Earth's magnetic lay lines.  In general (on average) is there a stronger magnetic field in geographical areas below sea level more than geographical areas above sea level?